# MATCH() AGAINST return no result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have these two functions for searching business' on my website. A user types a name and it should return business. But since I am MATCH(name) AGAINST, somehow it won't work. It works fine when I use  LIKE. But the problem is LIKE it has to be 100% match.

**EX:** If a business name is Nova Audio Studio, and user types nova, using LIKE won't do it. I even tried adding **IN BOOLEAN MODE** still the same.

```
public function search_result_count($search)
{
    $count=0;
    $search = addslashes($search);
    $city_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_city()->id;
    $sql="select count(id) as count from ".$this->table_name." where match(name) 
            against ('$search')>0 and city_id ='$city_id'";
    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
    if($row=$query->row())
    {
        $count=$row->count;
    }
    return $count;
}

public function search($search,$limit=10,$offset=0)
{
    $list = array();
    $search = addslashes($search);
    $city_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_city()->id;
    $sql="select biz.*,
            count( distinct photo.id) as photo_count,
            IF(count( distinct photo.id) > 0, sum(rating)/count( 
           distinct photo.id), sum(rating)) as rating_sum,
            count(distinct review.id) as review_num
    from ".$this->table_name." 
    left join review on biz.id = review.bizid
    left join photo on biz.id = photo.bizid
    where match(biz.name) against ('$search')>0 and biz.city_id ='$city_id' 
    group by biz.id
    limit $offset,$limit";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    foreach($query->result() as $biz)
    {
        if($biz->review_num > 0)
        {
            $biz->rating = (($biz->rating_sum/($biz- 
              >review_num*5))*100).'%';
        }
        else
        {
            $biz->rating = '0%';

        }
        $biz = biz_cat_info($biz);
        $biz->first_photo = $this->get_cover_photo($biz->id);
        $list[] = $biz;
    }
    return $list;

   }

       }
```

Thanks

Comment: Do your columns have full-text indexes? Also, have you tried using `LIKE` with a wildcard (`%`)?

Comment: @ginovva320 The only column with fulltext index is (name). I did try like with wildcard and didn't work

Comment: If this does not work `select X from Y where X LIKE '%Nova%'` when X contains **Nova Audio Studio** then something else is worng

Comment: Got it working, **where LENGTH('{$search}') > 1 AND name LIKE '%{$search}%'>0**